# How to cancel an intercepted $http request in angular based on its httpConfig info?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I am using angular-http-auth package that is an HTTP interceptor for angular that detects 401 Non-Authorized requests and allows to delay request and perform authorization before it.

However, I have a problem that authorization is another request and can be as well triggering 401 error. These requests I want to cancel as I will re-issue them.

In essence, I receieve such an event:

```
$scope.$on('event:auth-loginRequired', function (event, httpHeader) {

})
```

where event is JS `event` object and `httpHeader` is a set of data about request that was 401'd.

example of httpHeader:

```
{
  "data": "",
  "status": 401,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [null],
    "transformResponse": [null],
    "data": { "password": "wrqwfqwvcfqwfcq", "userName": "user123"},
    "url": "https://localhost:44300/api/authentication",
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "X-Auth-Token": "73r23r"
    },
    "withCredentials": true
  },
  "statusText": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I therefore analyze `httpHeader.config.url` and I might wish to cancel some particular URL requests  (leaving other pending requests untouched and waiting), preferably basing on `httpHeader` and event info received. How I can do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel"? Is it that you want to bypass the `angular-http-auth` for some requests?

Comment: @runTarm, no, to interrupt the request. The event is already inside http interceptor.

Comment: I don't think it is possible. What you can do seems to be either somehow bypass the module or cancel all the requests.